# Integration using scipy odeint

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

Why do below two versions of a same problem give different result y_phi, while all parameters are same and random values are seeded with same value in both versions ?
I know Version_1 gives correct result while Version_2 gives false result, why is that so?
Where am I making mistake in Version_2 ?

Version_1:

```
from numpy import *
import random
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def f(phi, t, alpha):
    v_phi = zeros(x*y, float)
    for n in range(x*y):
        cmean = cos(phi[n])
        smean = sin(phi[n])
        v_phi[n] = smean*cos(phi[n]+alpha)-cmean*sin(phi[n]+alpha)
    return v_phi

x = 5
y = 5
N = x*y
PI = pi
alpha = 0.2*PI
random.seed(1010)
phi = zeros(x*y, float)
for i in range(x*y):
    phi[i] = random.uniform(0.0, 2*PI)
t = arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)

y = odeint(f, phi, t, args=(alpha,))
y_phi = [y[len(t)-1, i] for i in range(N)]
print y_phi
```

Version_2:

```
def f(phi, t, alpha, cmean, smean):
    v_phi = zeros(x*y, float)
    for n in range(x*y):
        v_phi[n] = smean[n]*cos(phi[n]+alpha)-cmean[n]*sin(phi[n]+alpha)
    return v_phi

x = 5
y = 5
N = x*y
PI = pi
alpha = 0.2*PI
random.seed(1010)
phi = zeros(x*y, float)
for i in range(x*y):
    phi[i] = random.uniform(0.0, 2*PI)
t = arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)

cmean = []
smean = []
for l in range(x*y):
    cmean.append(cos(phi[l]))
    smean.append(sin(phi[l]))

y = odeint(f, phi, t, args=(alpha, cmean, smean,))
y_phi = [y[len(t)-1, i] for i in range(N)]
print y_phi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case `smean = cos(phi(t)[n])`, it depends on the current value of phi, but in the second `smean = cos(phi(0)[n])` and depends only on the initial value. (And similarly for `cmean`).

Btw, you could have found this issue also using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: I guess you are correct as result for array y_phi at t=0 are same in both version. I am interested in case 2 code. Is there a way to make smean in case II work like that in case I ? Anyway thanks for referring to Rubber_duck_debugging.

Comment: No: if you want to use the current value of phi, it is available only inside the `f` function.

Comment: Thanks for your useful suggestions in rectifying the issue.